# Conda environment not found when packaging dependencies for PySpark on YARN

Tags: python, pandas, apache-spark, pyspark, conda

I'm following this [guide](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/user_guide/python_packaging.html) to distribute pandas and pyarrow dependencies across executor nodes in my PySpark & YARN application. This is needed to run Pandas UDF's.

I am creating the Conda virtual environment like so:

```py
conda create -y -n pyspark_conda_env -c conda-forge pyarrow pandas conda-pack
conda activate pyspark_conda_env
conda pack -f -o pyspark_conda_env.tar.gz
```

Then submitting the Spark job:

```py
spark_job_config_path = '/tmp/spark_job_config.json'

            cmd = [
                "spark-submit",
                "--master",
                "yarn",
                "--deploy-mode",
                "client",
                "--archives",
                "/opt/program/pyspark_conda_env.tar.gz#environment",
                "/opt/program/image_analysis_launcher.py",
            ]
            cmd.extend([spark_job_config_path])

            subprocess.run(cmd, check = True)
```

I'm creating the Spark session as follows:

```py
spark = SparkSession.builder.master("yarn").config("spark.yarn.dist.archives", "pyspark_conda_env.tar.gz#environment").appName("AppName").getOrCreate()
```

After running the Docker container on which this program is located, I get the following error message:

```py
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling None.org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext.
: java.io.FileNotFoundException: File file:/usr/spark-3.1.2/pyspark_conda_env.tar.gz#environment does not exist
```

I've tried using the VirtualEnv and PEX to package the dependencies as well, but a similar error message appears. Any insight into why this is happening?

Answer (score 0):

I think you lose configure of python driver in your command.

In my case, my command is:

```bash
PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON=`which python` \  # set driver
PYSPARK_PYTHON=./snat/snat/bin/python \  # set python, in your case should be ./environment/bin/python
nohup /app/spark/bin/spark-submit \
--conf spark.yarn.appMasterEnv.PYSPARK_PYTHON=./snat/snat/bin/python \  # in your case should be ./environment/bin/python
--master yarn \
--deploy-mode client \
--num-executors 4 \
--executor-memory 2G \
--jars $(echo /path/to/jars/*.jar | tr ' ' ',') \
--archives hdfs:///user/root/cloud/snat.zip#snat \
features/main.py > yarn_pyspark_test.log &
```